# Access Variable outside Function I use another way but not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This Project build by Tkinter

I want to access path variable outside function:

This is my code :

```
excelName = None

def excel():

    global excelName
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Add a file", filetype=(("Excel", "*.xlsx")))

    path = filename
    excelName = os.path.basename(path) # This is Variable 

print(excelName) # This variable need to access from excel() function
```

The Result is :

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:\PycharmProjects\Test\excel.py

None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Where do you call the `excel` function?

Comment: Next question: Why a global variable? You can use a `return` to give back the name from the function.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Call it in same class.

Comment: @Matthias I have in this function 2 Variables, first path to use in script , second excelName to add in label  GUI

Answer (score 2):

First, you should call the `excel` function.
Second, the argument of `askopenfilename` should be `filetypes` not `filetype`.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def excel():
    global variable
    try:
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            title="Add a file", 
            filetypes=[("Excel", "*.xlsx")]
            )
    except FileNotFoundError:
        filename = ""
    if filename:
        variable = os.path.basename(filename)


def print_global_variable():
    global variable
    print(variable)


def main():
    global variable
    root = tk.Tk()
    variable = ""
    button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=excel)
    button_1.pack()
    button_2 = tk.Button(
        root, 
        text="Print Variable", 
        command=print_global_variable
    )
    button_2.pack()
    root.mainloop()


main()
```

Or, here is the class version:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        self.variable = ""
        self.button_1 = tk.Button(
            self, text="Click", command=self.excel
        )
        self.button_1.pack()
        self.button_2 = tk.Button(
            self, 
            text="Print Variable", 
            command=lambda: print(self.variable)
        )
        self.button_2.pack()


    def excel(self):
        try:
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                title="Add a file", 
                filetypes=[("Excel", "*.xlsx")]
                )
        except FileNotFoundError:
            filename = ""
        if filename:
            self.variable = os.path.basename(filename)


App(master=tk.Tk()).mainloop()
```

Comment: I use Button to open Dialog Box But After Use excel() the Dialog Box Open Automatic why? I don't want by this way

Comment: I am changing the codes, let's look at the new codes.

Comment: I use It Same Problem .